# Cannot link custom generated LLVM IR with Clang generated IR

Tags: llvm, clang++, llvm-ir

I've been trying to link IR generated with llvm's C++ api with a another IR file generated by Clang++. The input file to Clang is a function `fn` I'm trying to call from the first IR file. But `llvm-link` doesn't replace `fn`'s declaration with its definition.

**main_ir.ll**

```
source_filename = "top"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

@0 = private unnamed_addr constant [5 x i8] c"%d \0A\00", align 1

declare i32 @printf(...)

declare i32 @fn(i32, ...)

define internal i32 @main() {
  entrypoint:
  %f_call = call i32 (i32, ...) @fn(i32 2)
  %printfCall = call i32 (...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @0, 
  i32 0, i32 0), i32 %f_call)
  br label %ProgramExit

ProgramExit:                                      ; preds = %entrypoint
   ret i32 0
}
```

**fn_ir.ll** (generated with Clang)

```
source_filename = "libDessin.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @_Z2fni(i32) #0 {
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %4 = mul nsw i32 %3, 2
  ret i32 %4
}

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp- 
  math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "min-legal-vector- 
  width"="0" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp- 
  math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp- 
  math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target- 
  cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" 
  "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!1 = !{!"clang version 9.0.1-12 "}
```

And all llvm-link does is reproduce the contents of **fn_ir.ll** with the `source_filename` changed to `llvm-link`. I'd be real happy to know the bit I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the name mangling.

Your 'manually' generated IR has a function named `fn`, while `clang++` emits the name `_Z2fni`.

You need to make the names match. Either emit the `_Z2fni` in the `main_ir.ll`, or (arguable better in this case) change the definition of `fn` in the `fn_ir`, e.g.:

```
extern "C" void fn(int x) {
  return x * 2;
}
```

`extern "C"` tells the compiler to use C mangling convention, this is less fragile since it will work even if you change type or number of arguments of `fn`. However, it won't work if you want to pass C++ types into the `fn`, then you need to emit the right function name for the `main_ir.ll`.

**UPD:**

There two more 'discrepancies':

1. The `fn` has different arguments in the two modules: `i32` vs `i32, ...`
2. The other issue is that `main` declared as internal. I guess it is just stripped since it is internal and it is not being called by anyone.

So just removing the `internal` flag should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @AlexDenisov. However that doesn't seem to be the problem. Adding `extern "C"` does demangle the function name but the linked file still contains only the contents of `fn_ir.ll`. 'llvm-link'  just ignores `main_ir.ll`

Comment: @droptop I added another comment, that should fix the issue you are having :)

Comment: thanks a lot mate it worked. I still don't know how I missed the `externallinkage` thing... :) :) :)